# Can't open dmcrypt drive after integrity error

Tags: linux, devices, luks, cryptsetup, integrity

I'm using dm-integrity on this drive using cryptsetup directly I formatted it with
cryptsetup luksFormat --hash sha384 --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --integrity hmac-sha1.

After a while I thing some data got "corrupted". The disk also maybe failing, but I'm able to open it with luksOpen with no problems. I will replace the disk but I need the data it have. So I need a solution of maybe recalculate the checksum in the area that is reporting integrity error so I can open the disk normally

Here is the full dmesg log.

```
[sex jan 27 17:10:20 2023] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 0.01
[sex jan 27 17:10:20 2023] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[sex jan 27 17:10:20 2023] usb 1-6: Product: AS2115
[sex jan 27 17:10:20 2023] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[sex jan 27 17:10:20 2023] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 00000000000000000000
[sex jan 27 17:10:20 2023] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[sex jan 27 17:10:20 2023] scsi host16: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[sex jan 27 17:10:21 2023] scsi 16:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2115             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[sex jan 27 17:10:21 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Spinning up disk...
[sex jan 27 17:10:22 2023] ..ready
[sex jan 27 17:10:23 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
[sex jan 27 17:10:23 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
[sex jan 27 17:10:23 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[sex jan 27 17:10:23 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[sex jan 27 17:10:23 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI disk
[sex jan 27 17:14:41 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=1s
[sex jan 27 17:14:41 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[sex jan 27 17:14:41 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[sex jan 27 17:14:41 2023] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdh] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 01 db f0 00 00 f0 00
[sex jan 27 17:14:41 2023] critical medium error, dev sdh, sector 121840 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 8 prio class 2                                                                     
[sex jan 27 17:14:42 2023] device-mapper: integrity: Error on reading journal: -5
[sex jan 27 17:14:42 2023] buffer_io_error: 6 callbacks suppressed
[sex jan 27 17:14:42 2023] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-19, logical block 75185344, async page read                                                                                               
[sex jan 27 17:14:42 2023] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-19, logical block 75185344, async page read                                                                                               
[sex jan 27 17:14:42 2023] F2FS-fs (dm-19): Unable to read 1th superblock
[sex jan 27 17:14:42 2023] F2FS-fs (dm-19): Unable to read 2th superblock
```

If I try to mount the device I get the following error
"impossible to read superblock on /dev/mapper/sdh."

I think dm-integrity is not letting me to open the device without correcting the integrity error first.

If I try to use fsck I get the following error:

```
e2fsck -b 32768 
e2fsck: Input/output error while try to open /dev/mapper/sdh
```

Comment: is it ext234 or f2fs as the error message suggests?

Comment: ddrescue first, you can't do recovery on a faulty drive.

Comment: @frostschutz, ddrescue says it's high hundred of megabytes in error rate. I think luks isn't letting anything access the drive because of the integrity error. It is ext4 indeed, but I use other filesystems that are f2fs

Comment: You are rescuing the bare drive, and not the integrity device? If it's an USB enclosure you can also try connecting the drive directly instead. But it seems like this might be a hopeless case…